# Private field in java annotations

Tags: java, annotations, javac

My jboss seam application compile in eclipse without error. When I try to compile manually I have had a error

> STATE_QUERY has private access

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = CurrentModuleState.FIND_MODULE_STATE,
         query = CurrentModuleState.STATE_QUERY)
})
public class CurrentModuleState implements java.io.Serializable {
        ...
        private static final String STATE_QUERY = "...";
```

ant:

```
<javac encoding="cp1251" srcdir="${src-dir}" destdir="${compile-dir}"
            executable="${javac-path}"
            compiler="javac1.6">
    <classpath refid="lib.classpath" />
    <classpath refid="jboss-lib.classpath" />
</javac>
```

How I can compile that?
p.s. sorry for my engish )

Comment: Welcome to SO. I guess by "manually" you mean compiled with ant? Could you go into the preferences in Eclipse and post the compiler settings from there?

Comment: Yes. "manually" it means compiled with ant. I can't find compiler settings in eclipse. Where is it?

Comment: Compiler settings won't matter much as eclipse uses it's own parser and compiler process, which happily compiles some of the more obscure constructs that Sun's javac chokes on. Most of the problems are with Java 1.5 code like generics or annotations in this case.

Comment: See this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359474/java-type-level-annotation-and-private-member-visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an odd thing, But I would suppose it is because the field is `private` but is accessed using the class name in front. The compiler should realize it is referred from the same class, but it obviously doesn't.

So, change the `private` to `protected` (not elegant, but should work)

You can also try upgrading the JDK (and hence javac). Note that eclipse uses its own compiler (not javac)

Comment: Or `query = CurrentModuleState.this.STATE_QUERY` maybe?

Comment: @dimafeng _how_ it doesn't work? Is it the same compilation error? a different one?

Comment: well, the other thing is - try to upgrade the JDK (and hence the compiler)

Comment: if the problem in version of jdk then eclipse would not be able to compile that, but eclipse compile without errors.

Comment: not true - eclipse uses its own compiler, which differs from `javac`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question but I don't really see the point of using a constant for the query itself. I would just use something like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = Customer.FIND_ALL, query="select c from Customer c"),
public class Customer {
    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Customer.findAll";
    // Attributes, constructors, getters, setters
}
```

And the constant is `public` because... I want to be able to use it to execute queries:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Customer.FIND_ALL);
List<Customer> customers = query.getResultList();
```

Using a constant for the name of the query makes sense because you'll refer to it from several places (from the `@NamedQuery` annotation, when invoking the query) and  a constant makes your code more robust: it will resist to typing mistakes and refactoring. The advantages are obvious.

However, I personally don't see any real advantage in using a constant for the query itself.

Comment: Thanks. We decided to move all queries in public interface.